# Installing Font from Web Server to Client PC through JQuery or Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, fonts

I am developing an application in ASP.Net using C#. In my application I am using some fonts which are very uncommon. Most of the PC doesn't have those fonts. So I want to implement a concept that first my application will check the font is installed in the client PC or not. If not installed then application will download that font and install it to the client PC automatically so that User will get proper view of the site. How can I do that? Please help me.

Comment: What have you tried? You should look into the [`AddFontResource()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183326%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

Comment: Why download? can't you use [@font-face](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/) css rule?

Comment: @urbz He is creating ASP.NET application and not desktop application so the link is not useful for him